# Saving a php file in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I've just started using WordPress. I'm trying to add posts to Wordpress using php, and I came across this piece of code:

```
// Create post object
$my_post = array(
  'post_title'    => 'My post',
  'post_content'  => 'This is my post.',
  'post_status'   => 'publish',
  'post_author'   => 1,
  'post_category' => array(8,39)
);

// Insert the post into the database
wp_insert_post( $my_post );
```

I understand this is the way to go when creating a post using php. My questions are:

1. How do we execute the above PHP script and where do we save it in the WordPress folder?
2. What does the `post_category` array mean(I'd like to use a category id to add posts to WordPress)?

I'd like to mention that I've done some descent searching on the net, but the resources I've found do not mention how to execute the above script.

Comment: 1. Where you need it? 2. Yes, they're category ids.

Comment: Why are you adding the post programmatically instead of through admin? Yes, `post_author` and `post_category` refer to the IDs of such.  You'd want to put this in functions.php and then call it by either attaching it to an action hook or running it some other way.

Comment: It's hard to help when you don't explain why you would want to add a post this way, especially if you don't understand PHP or WordPress and when you can just as easily do this via the admin panel.

Comment: Pretty much this covers it all http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post

Comment: Ennui, i'm familiar with adding a post through the back end..my aim is to use a category id to be able to add multiple posts to it as i think it would be the easier way